# VLOOKUP and IF Function In One Excel Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've found how to embed multiple IF functions and how to input a `VLOOKUP` and `IF` function, but I think my situation is unique still.

I have this function inputted into a cell:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N3,'Pivot Tables'!$D:$E,2,FALSE),0)
```

It pulls from a Pivot Table and if there is no answer it displays 0.  The numbers in the Pivot Table are average number of `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` between two dates.

The problem is that I don't want it to count the first day in the count.  I can make it subtract one day to the formula like so:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N3,'Pivot Tables'!$D:$E,2,FALSE),0)-1
```

But I'm transferring that data into a chart and don't want / can't have "-1" displayed on the chart.  What do I need to do to insert an IF function so that if the count is less than zero it displays zero?

I was trying to use `if<0="0"`, but I can't get it to input correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @PeterH answer works, it has the downside of repeating the VLOOKUP, which is not great from a maintenance point of view.

For this particular case you can use MAX instead of an IF:

```
=MAX(0,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N3,'Pivot Tables'!$D:$E,2,FALSE),0)-1)
```

Comment: Am I reading the string correctly that it gives the max number, but starts at zero?

Comment: @P.Looker it gives the maximum between zero and the result of the other formula. If the result is negative, the maximum is zero. If the result is positive the maximum is the result. For instance `=MAX(0,2)` would always return 2.